# Check if program is in path

Tags: sh

Can sh itself check if a program exists or is in path?

I.e., not with the help of the "which" program.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if a program exists from a bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe sh can directly.  But perhaps something like:

```
which() {
  save_IFS=$IFS
  IFS=:
  for d in $PATH; do
    test -x $d/$1 && echo $d/$1
  done
  IFS=$save_IFS
}
```

and here's a nice variation that uses a subshell so that restoring IFS is not necessary:

```
which() (
  IFS=:
  for d in $PATH; do
    test -x $d/$1 && echo $d/$1
  done
)
```

Also, (in bash) if the command has been executed in the past and bash has already done the PATH search, you can see what it found with hash -t.

```
bash-3.2$ hash -t which
bash: hash: which: not found
bash-3.2$ which foo
bash-3.2$ hash -t which
/usr/bin/which
```

Comment: These functions won't work quite properly for a `PATH` with a colon at the beginning or end or a `::`, all of which mean `search the current directory`.

Answer (score 2):

The utility `command -v $CMD` is apparently a portable option (in the sense of being part of POSIX); see also the very similar (though bash-specific) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script), in particular [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4785518/36585).